# Using a public access token for GitHub with Neo4j

Tags: github, neo4j

I'm trying to use LOAD CSV with a CSV file stored in GitHub. It works fine with the 10 minute, temporary token you get when viewing the raw file, but I want something that's more persistent, as I need to be able to deploy this to multiple environments. Ten minutes just won't cut it.

I figured a private access token would be the way forward, but (once again) GitHub's spectacularly poor quality documentation made this much harder than it should be.

I set up a private access token with the repo and read:org permissions and with this I can get at my files using CURL, e.g.

`curl -s https://<my_token>@raw.githubusercontent.com/<my repo>/<path>/<my file>.csv`

This works fine and I see the contents of my test file.

But if I try to navigate to that URL I just get a 404 error and if I use it in Neo4j with a LOAD CSV statement, I get an error `couldn't load the external resource at:`.

I'm basically doing this:

`LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM '<URL that worked in CURL>' AS row`

...and it fails miserably.

Where:

`LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM '<URL for raw file from GitHub with 10 minute token>' AS row`

works fine, so I know I can access external files, i.e. files not in the import directory.

Is this just a failing with GitHub, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: can you copy and paste your https:// / /myfile.csv into a browser. Does it work when you try to browse the csv file?

Comment: Yes I tried that - it doesn't work. So it only works if I use CURL - no idea what's going on there :(

Comment: The github repository is set to private settings so you need tokens; if you can put it in a public repo/project, then you will not need the token.

Comment: Putting my files into a public repository isn't an option. My problem isn't with the token (this works fine), it's the fact that Neo4j doesn't seem to like it for some reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I hate answering my own questions, I left this kicking around a while and nobody came back with anything that helped.

I now know a whole lot more about public access tokens than I ever wanted to, but it was all worthwhile, as it helped me get around this issue.

There's an `apoc.load.jsonParams` function that accepts bearer tokens. From here it didn't take too much work to get this working the same way that LOAD CSV had done.

There was one last gotcha though, I soon discovered that the URLs for the repository can't include spaces or other non-alphanumeric characters, but that's a small price to pay for success?

So this doesn't work:

`LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'https://<my_token>@raw.githubusercontent.com/<my repo>/<path>/<my file>.csv' AS row...`

Instead I had to use:

`CALL apoc.load.jsonParams("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/<my repo>/<path>/<my file>.json", {Authorization: "Bearer <token>"}, null) YIELD value WITH value AS row...`

There's an equivalent `apoc.load.csvParams` procedure, but I never tested this.